# Remove last line from a jTextPane

Tags: java

I have a `jTextPane` and two buttons add and undo. When I press the button add, it adds a new line in the `jTextPane`. This is a sample:

```
jTextPane1.getStyledDocument().insertString(jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength(), "\n New Item:", null);
```

How can I remove the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the job: first get the position of the last newline in the content of the document, then remove content from that position till the end:

```
String content = jTextPane1.getDocument().getText(0, jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength());
int lastLineBreak = content.lastIndexOf('\n');
jTextPane1.getDocument().remove(lastLineBreak, jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength() - lastLineBreak);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last `.length()` be `.getLength()`?

Comment: `if (lastLineBreak == -1) {lastLineBreak = 0;}` will be needed if `jTextPane1` is empty